# Is "git lfs install" included in "git lfs migrate"?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Git lfs documentation says :

```
Setup Git LFS on your system. You only have to do this once per
    repository per machine:

        git lfs install
```

Now, since how I don't know the extent of what `git lfs install` does, how could I check `git lfs migrate` has called `git lfs install` (which is not said in `git lfs migrate` doc : https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/git-lfs/git-lfs-migrate.1.en.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git lfs migrate` does not call `git lfs install`.  You need to run `git lfs install` once per user and machine pair unless you have set up the filters appropriately by hand.

The command installs the filter commands which invoke Git LFS into the user's `~/.gitconfig` file and the hooks in the present repository.  Those hooks are also installed when certain Git LFS commands are invoked in a repository for the first time, but that will only happen if `git lfs install` has been run or the filters have been appropriately configured.

Besides installing the hooks, the `git lfs install` command runs the following:

```
git config --global filter.lfs.process "git-lfs filter-process"
git config --global filter.lfs.smudge "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config --global filter.lfs.clean "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Running those commands, or making the equivalent edits, is sufficient to get Git LFS working without running `git lfs install`.

If you are using Git LFS from Debian, the filter commands may have already been set up for you, and you can check that by inspecting `/etc/gitconfig`.  If so, you need not run them yourself, although you may want to anyway in case you end up using a non-Debian system.

Comment: So for you it's "once per user and machine" and not "once per repository per machine" as said in the doc ?

Comment: It's once per user and machine.